# pip install vs python -m pip install with virtualenvs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I know this has been asked several times here on StackOverflow and that some questions remained unanswered, but I want to give it a try.

On several remote machines I have access to, once activated a virtual environment (created with `python -m venv`, I am not using conda) I can run either `pip install` or `python -m pip install` with similar results: packages are installed within the current virtual environment. So, right after installing a new package `P`, I can run `python` and then run `import P` at the python prompt without errors.

Not on a machine I am working on right now (with python version 3.6.9, Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). On this machine the two commands are different. All the tests I describe below have been made with a fresh environment (the only one I have), created after I deleted all the references to previous installations from the hidden folders in `~`.

1. if I activate the virtual environment `env1`, install a package `P` with `pip install P`, then run python and import the new package, the interpreter cannot find the package P.
2. After 1, if I deactivate the virtualenv, run python and try to import P, I get another error due to the missing module `P`.
3. **where did pip install `P`?**
4. Installation within the virtual environment is fine with `python -m pip install`.

However, when I activate the environment `env1`, I get this:

`$-> which pip`

`/home/user/env1/bin/pip`

and

`$-> which python`

`/home/user/env1/bin/python`

Indeed, that folder is the first in the `$PATH` variable.

So, theoretically, `pip` resides within the virtual environment. Theoretically, it should install packages in the same environment as `python -m pip install`.

What did I not understand?

Is there any chance I can have `pip install` and `python -m pip install` behave in the same way with respect to the active virtual environment?

-- **UPDATE & SOLVED** thanks to @phd comment. You are right, phd, I should have checked the information you asked, you solved the issue!!! Thanks!

*no active virtual environment:*

```
type -a python pip
python is aliased to `/usr/bin/python3'
python is /usr/bin/python
bash: type: pip: not found
```

*env1 active*

```
python is aliased to `/usr/bin/python3'
python is /home/user/env1/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
pip is /home/user/env1/bin/pip

head -1 $(which pip)
#!/home/user/env1/bin/python3
```

The issue here was the `python` alias: I removed the alias (that I did not create btw, it is system-wide) and `pip install` became equivalent to `python -m pip install`. Very obvious now, not during the hour spent looking for the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `which` is not enough. Try `type -a python pip` — are there aliases or shell functions? Also check pip's [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)): `head -1 $(which pip)` — is it `/home/user/env1/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/env python` ?

Comment: Thanks @phd your comment solved the issue.